# Netbeans debugging remotely (Xdebug)

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I have created a remote sourced php project on an Amazon ec2 server, which I am editing the source code from netbeans from my local windows 7 machine and uploading to the ec2 instance with SFTP.

Uploading the code is working fine and the application itself is working fine. However when I try to debug the code netbeans will NOT stop at any breakpoints.

I have mapped the server path and project path in the Run Configuration category on netbeans as specified in the documentation [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html#debug_url).

I have also tried adding the following to my php.ini on my ec2 server

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=<ip address>
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/log/xdebug.log"
```

Where the ip address = my server's IP address.

Comment: Can you please post your /tmp/log/xdebug.log file as well - or atleast an extract of it where it makes connections and 10/20 lines above and below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remote_host setting should be the IP address of the **machine that runs the IDE**. You need to make sure that the EC2 instance with Xdebug can connect to port 9000 on the network interface that talks to the EC2 instance. If you do this from a local LAN with NAT, then you would need to setup a tunnel. There might be some hints at http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html to help you with tunnels.